# Timeout child thread for python3

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

I am quite new to programming and I am running Linux, python3.5

There are a few similar questions in Stack Overflow but most of them do not have any response

like: [[Python 2.7 multi-thread]In Python, how to timeout a function call in sub-thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221907/python-2-7-multi-threadin-python-how-to-timeout-a-function-call-in-sub-thread), and [Python , Timeout on a function on child thread without using signal and thread.join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646431/python-timeout-on-a-function-on-child-thread-without-using-signal-and-thread-j)

I am able to use signal when it is in main thread and timeout for multiprocess. However, the function I am currently running is a child thread using apscheduler (or it can be started directly)

```
schedule.add_job(test_upload.run, 'interval', seconds=10, start_date='2016-01-01 00:00:05',
                    args=['instant'])
```

and I can't convert it to child process because I am sharing database connection.

I have also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/36904264/2823816, but terminal said

```
  result = await future.result(timeout = timeout)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in

```
import concurrent

def run():
    return 1

timeout = 10

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(run) # get a future object
    try:
        result = await future.result(timeout = timeout)
    except concurrent.futures.TimeOutError:
        result = None
```

I am now very sure how to solve it:( Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you add any code for reference?

Comment: @thatrockbottomprogrammer, I have added some code for reference. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you on a version that supports await syntax (if not, there’s your syntax error)? And what has the code you linked has to do with your code? Please post the code that you ran that caused the error.

Comment: @abccd I have modification to the post accordingly.

Comment: you cant ever have an await outside of an coroutine function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up timing out the thread in my child thread.

So I used multi-process within the child thread to kill it. I could not find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dozysun/timeout-timer,  work fine in sub thread which use sub thread as timer